# JPA 2.0 Entity update with new relationship fails on persist but succeeds on merge

Tags: jpa-2.0, eclipselink

I have the following relationships defined

Entity A has @OneToMany with Entity B that has @OneToOne with Entity C.

At the time of creation for Entity A, I also create Entity B and set the relationship between them. Everything works as expected.

In another transaction, 
- Entity A is fetched from the DB, the corresponding Entity B is fetched and then
- Entity C is created. 
- Entity C is set on Entity B to forge the relationship between the two. 
If i use EntityManager.persist(Entity B), the persistence manager tries and inserts Entity B into the DB again causing a unique constraint violation on the PK of Entity B. 
If i user EntityManager.merge(Entity B), everything works as desired.

In this above context of use, why would a persist operation try and create a duplicate since the Entity is managed in this case and it should easily be able to do an update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPA requires providers to throw an exception if persist is called on an unmanaged instance.  Only merge can be used since it is clear that it takes the data from the instance and merges it into a managed copy.  If B were managed, the persist call would be ignored, so it means that some how B gets detached or that it was read in a different entityManager from the one you call persist on.

Comment: Yes, B is getting read by a different entityManager instance. If an app is deployed only in a web container (not EE), a service locator pattern is probably useful to manage the persistence resources. I know the Entity Manager Factory is thread safe. What about the Entity Manager instance itself? Does it make sense to use a service locator pattern to provide a shared Entity Manager instance for the entire application?

Comment: EntityManagers are not thread safe, and are meant to represent transactional contexts.  If you are creating Entity C within a transaction, B should be fetched from the same EM so that the managed instance is associate to C.  It wouldn't be good to share a single EM for the entire app, but it would make sense to be shared for logical units of work, and then get closed or cleared afterward.